# Migrating domain to new server. mysql migration Error 1881

Tags: wordpress, mysql, error, migration

Wordpress 4.3.1

CiviCRM 4.5.5

Old host: Apache 2.2.26 - PHP: 5.3.28 - MySQL: 5.1.73

New host: Apache 2.2.29 - PHP: 5.3.29 - MySQL: 5.6.23

My only export options on the old host are via phpMyAdmin or cpanel export on the old host. I basically get a data.sql.gz file.

When I do this in ssh on the new host:

```
mysql -u username -p -h localhost DATA-BASE-NAME < data.sql
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR 1881 (HY000) at line 48: Operation not allowed when innodb_forced_recovery > 0.
```

What can I do with my sql file or from the old host's phpMyAdmin so that the data import properly into the new host?

Comment: Could you provide the SQL statement at line 48 of the file?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The line is too long for this venue. (5698 characters)   
It starts:    
`INSERT INTO `civicrm_acl` (`id`, `name`, `deny`, `entity_table`, `entity_id`, `operation`, `object_table`, `object_id`, `acl_table`, `acl_id`, `is_active`) VALUES (1,'Edit All Contacts',0,'civicrm_acl_role',1,'Edit','civicrm_saved_search',0,NULL,NULL,1),`
  
and ends  
  
`,(65,'Core ACL',0,'civicrm_acl_role',2,'All','view event info',NULL,NULL,NULL,1);`

Comment: Line 47: `/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `civicrm_acl` DISABLE KEYS */;`

Line 49: `/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `civicrm_acl` ENABLE KEYS */;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears from [this other StackExchange answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25155777/operation-not-allowed-when-innodb-forced-recovery-0-sqlyog) that the MySQL on the new server may be set to read only. Try opening the my.cnf configuration file for MySQL and changing the setting.

Comment: Thanks, Joe Murray. Apparently a setting of `innodb_force_recovery = 1` in /etc/my.cnf causes tables that are innodb format to be read only. I'm trying to get the hosting box owner to change it. Please stand by.

Comment: PS If a StackExchange answer addresses your question/problem, then it is good form to check it as accepted, and to up-vote it. But I get it that you don't yet know if this will solve the issue.